# How to reconnect tcp connection when device is reboot

Tags: c#, android, tcp

It is communication issue between Android and PC.
The smartphone is a host, waiting for a connection, and when the pc is connected, the smartphone continues to send information to the pc.

I wanna reconnect tcp even if the smartphone reboot. The smartphone is waiting to be connected again even if after reboot. If the smartphone is turned off, the connected value is still 'true'. And received 'null' value.
What should I do to connect again at this time?`

```
TcpClient MyTcpClient;
int myPort = 4000;
StreamWriter MyWriter;
StreamReader MyReader;

int port = GetFreePort();

MyTcpClient = new TcpClient(IPAddress.Loopback.Tostring(), port);
MyTcpClient.ReceiveTimeout = 30000;

MyReader = new StreamReader(MyTcpClient.GetStream());
MyWriter = new StreamWriter(MyTcpClient.GetStream());

while(MyTcpClient.Connected) //if device is off, it still true
{
    string line = MyReader.ReadLine();// when device is off, it is null
}
```

I want reconnect Tcp connection if device is reboot.

Answer (score 0):

As long as i know , you have to configure ReceiveTimeout for both client and server .

and using socket will give you so much more options , like

SetSocketOption( SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, true ) .